# Only the first series in Microsoft .NET stacked column chart control displays tooltip correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, .net-4.0

The following tooltip has been added to the stacked column chart series:

```
    foreach (Series s in ch.Series)
    {
        s.ToolTip = "#VALX: #SERIESNAME - #VALY";
    }
```

However, only the lowest stacked series in every column displays proper value for `#VALX`, ex:

`Sales: From $0 to $1000 - 6`

All other series above display `0` instead:

```
0: From $1001 to $10,000 - 19
0: From $10001 to $20,000 - 4
```

What am I doint wrong?

Comment: I'll wait from the suggestions from the others. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumble into this, try #AXISLABEL instead of #VALX